# Midnight Commander does not start without internet connection

Tags: mc

I've got some aarch64 embedded device with Centos 7.4. If the system has internet connection, the mc starts as it should. But after disconnection it just didn't starts, but it possible to exit with Ctrl+C.

Comment: Give it 60 seconds to start. Does it start?

Comment: Well, yes, it did starts, but it takes slightly more than 60 sec - about 2 minutes (I'm using slow ssh chain to get to the network where it is). Is it possible to do smth?

Comment: mc does some checks, never found it out to get around it. Have you your PROMPT shell var readonly, btw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mc` is slow starting, but it does start.

Had a problem in the past of slow `mc` start, strace'd it, and found out if does delays waiting for some specific conditions/tests.

In my case, it asked for a change in the PROMPT shell variable, and was waiting for a change, and then timed out in roughly 60 seconds. It timed out because my PROMPT was readonly.

TLDR Those wait times *appear* to be there by design. If you manage to find out *why*, it might be worth filling a bug about it.

Comment: My PROMPT is not readonly, but I find the root of the problem in other questions here: host ``hostname`` command takes this time to execute. Adding my host name to /etc/hosts didn't help, but I will look into futher. Thanks

Comment: With "absent network" related delays, DNS timeouts come to mind. Did you change the search order in `/etc/host.conf`?

Comment: @RudiC I have been a regular for many years and never noticed delays due to lack of DNS.

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro: If there's no internet connection, and depending on how his/her backup / fallback / caching name server is set up, I'd expect (and had in the past) timeout delays.

Comment: @Rudic My fault was not clear. Never noticed delays *in mc* due to lack of network connectivity. Nowadays we are connect most of the time, but in the past did not have an Internet connection at home, and never noticed any *mc* delays.